# Percent Variance Explained - Factor Analysis

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I am doing factor analysis using the factanal() function in R, estimating 4 factors on 60 variables of data (~1500 total observations) using the varimax rotation (so not PCA). I want to compute the percent variance explained by each factor, *for only a specific subgroup of variables in the data.* I could then compare this to the total percent variance explained for a factor model estimated separately only for that subgroup of variables of interest. This would tell me if my 'full' factor model does a good job of explaining the variables in the subgroup relative to a factor model estimated only on that subgroup, or a 'partial' model.

Normally, I understand you would compute the Sum of Squared Loadings/N for the percent variance explained *overall* of each factor. I.E. Factor 1 explains x% of the data, Factor 2 explains y% etc. Does this method also work if I want to see how much of the variation, for example, Factor 1 explains for only variables 1 through 10? I'm computing the SSL/N only for those variables where N is 10. Is this is a valid procedure?

Threads such as this provide a good overview of using SSL/N for a rotated factor model, but in SPSS: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205459/whats-the-relationship-between-initial-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-squared-loadings

Comment: So your question is "Is this is a valid procedure?" That's not a programming question that's right for Stack Overflow. If you have questions about the use of statistical models, you should be asking your question over at [stats.se] in order to get the most helpful answers.